# Multi-language Google Translate API is returing (503) Server Unavailable

Tags: c#, google-translate, http-status-code-503, downloadstring

I am trying to use Google Translate to translate but it gives error Server Unavailable. What my guess is that when I try to put same thing in the address bar we receive a captcha to fill in. If we get thru the captcha than only it downloads a txt file. I am thinking this might be the issue of captcha page and not the Server Unavailable.

### **Calling Function.**

```
string result = TranslateGoogle("Life is great and one is spoiled when it goes on and on and on", "en", "hi");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

### **TranslateGoogle Function**

```
public string TranslateGoogle(string text, string fromCulture, string toCulture)
{
    fromCulture = fromCulture.ToLower();
    toCulture = toCulture.ToLower();
    string[] tokens = fromCulture.Split('-');
    if(tokens.Length > 1)
        fromCulture = tokens[0];

    tokens = toCulture.Split('-');
    if(tokens.Length > 1)
        toCulture = tokens[0];

    string url = string.Format(@"http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=j&text={0}&hl=en&sl={1}&tl={2}", System.Uri.EscapeDataString(text), fromCulture, toCulture);

    string html = null;
    try
    {
        WebClient web = new WebClient();

        web.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0");
        web.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, "UTF-8");

        web.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        html = web.DownloadString(url);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }

    string result = Regex.Match(html, "trans\":(\".*?\"),\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
    return result;
}
```

### **Expected Output**

```
{
    "sentences":
    [
        {
            "trans":"जीवन महान है और इस पर और पर और पर चला जाता है जब एक खराब है",
            "orig":"Life is great and one is spoiled when it goes on and on and on",
            "translit":"Jīvana mahāna hai aura isa para aura para aura para calā jātā hai jaba ēka kharāba hai",
            "src_translit":"",
            "backend":0
        }
    ],
    "src":"en",
    "server_time":85
}
```

### **This is what I am getting.**

> "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable."

What should I be doing to get the expected output for the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is not an answer(but maybe the community can help and let this become a real answer), but I need to post here because in comment I can't format well.

I tried your example and it seems that google thinks that you are trying to abuse their services, here is what client sends:

```
GET http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=j&text=Life%20is%20great%20and%20one%20is%20spoiled%20when%20it%20goes%20on%20and%20on%20and%20on&hl=en&sl=en&tl=hi HTTP/1.1
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Host: translate.google.com
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Google sends this request to **http://ipv4.google.com/sorry/IndexRedirect**?continue=http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t%3Fclient%3Dj%26text%3DLife%2520is%2520great%2520and%2520one%2520is%2520spoiled%2520when%2520it%2520goes%2520on%2520and%2520on%2520and%2520on%26hl%3Den%26sl%3Den%26tl%3Dhi&q=CGMSBFgz6X4YkI3frwUiGQDxp4NLo-2RV2k8i7UPzIRYKSuT5usFkUU

here, if navigated from browser it shows captcha, so I tried navigating the url generated by the program using web browser (Firefox).
That's what it shows:
[image: Google Captcha]

Sorry for the italian, it says that an unusual traffic is coming from the PC.
Once you prompt the captcha correctly your browser saves a cookie for the next requests(so you won't get the captcha again) and you are redirected to the translated sentence.

Here is an example of the browser requests on next navigations:

```
GET http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=j&text=Life%20is%20great%20and%20one%20is%20spoiled%20when%20it%20goes%20on%20and%20on%20and%20on&hl=en&sl=en&tl=hi HTTP/1.1
Host: translate.google.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Cookie: NID=71=a__xJqNU4C1oQTkLrMCSL4CLdR_nelc5kbjcUwgvJUBILn2SOHrfUeIg-9vWfy6tRHVh9Z4yXT1dpwnnHIXf5i2NLlCuDn-joB1tpYo_9JM4_zQnaaYO7UCsFoFILogS8G4XTt1M8esMgUnG_JzoMWSG81Q-JfGk1_IQsb5gIHyHcKroJeNEUp4bnMkiOvZgj1Sk; SID=DQAAAP8AAADnhNjYLtZUYSPbm-V_62WNnlSj8pUKPRnUfLR-Fp18gYeyWsC93YgLn5yoy0L3FLPb2_yNM7ysBQPCnqJGCy6Or6i2WLHicMaVFr0_0LT4xM2KECq3F6Nczc6V7RO8G5VYnHNLXjZ4ZqVMRTfG3E-Ljrgq_0zg_bhi1DT2CeWoBgBFSVTh_cyMjjYdCRiPpyEFRAtUp_48EKmd62YzJHyPeD-JfXTvVlyacDavPzl4L5yf1KmJ37c-j_Px8dYVKHn5tE_jAKHcFjJ717mY85bjyyUasTKoPc_w9AhnVQXE-v-jBsT4rvbJ3khIqiddjagnQ6LpVCMrRwZ9OwU2uubG; HSID=AX4zDBkEvzB-ZdrnV; APISID=ZMLtLIl8PnW6C6X2/A20GPxC9NiRmY3t1T; _ga=GA1.3.1956353841.1435321193; PREF=ID=1111111111111111:FF=0:LD=it:TM=1436338644:LM=1437143045:V=1:S=me455Y_9_LyG2PFU; GOOGLE_ABUSE_EXEMPTION=ID=52cecb7a44e552cc:TM=1442301156:C=c:IP=88.51.233.126-:S=APGng0tXDRxFvrRNJHu-uk3IRqKVpJAIIQ
Connection: keep-alive
```

As a proof if I add this line to the C# code:

```
web.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "NID=71=a__xJqNU4C1oQTkLrMCSL4CLdR_nelc5kbjcUwgvJUBILn2SOHrfUeIg-9vWfy6tRHVh9Z4yXT1dpwnnHIXf5i2NLlCuDn-joB1tpYo_9JM4_zQnaaYO7UCsFoFILogS8G4XTt1M8esMgUnG_JzoMWSG81Q-JfGk1_IQsb5gIHyHcKroJeNEUp4bnMkiOvZgj1Sk; SID=DQAAAP8AAADnhNjYLtZUYSPbm-V_62WNnlSj8pUKPRnUfLR-Fp18gYeyWsC93YgLn5yoy0L3FLPb2_yNM7ysBQPCnqJGCy6Or6i2WLHicMaVFr0_0LT4xM2KECq3F6Nczc6V7RO8G5VYnHNLXjZ4ZqVMRTfG3E-Ljrgq_0zg_bhi1DT2CeWoBgBFSVTh_cyMjjYdCRiPpyEFRAtUp_48EKmd62YzJHyPeD-JfXTvVlyacDavPzl4L5yf1KmJ37c-j_Px8dYVKHn5tE_jAKHcFjJ717mY85bjyyUasTKoPc_w9AhnVQXE-v-jBsT4rvbJ3khIqiddjagnQ6LpVCMrRwZ9OwU2uubG; HSID=AX4zDBkEvzB-ZdrnV; APISID=ZMLtLIl8PnW6C6X2/A20GPxC9NiRmY3t1T; _ga=GA1.3.1956353841.1435321193; PREF=ID=1111111111111111:FF=0:LD=it:TM=1436338644:LM=1437143045:V=1:S=me455Y_9_LyG2PFU; GOOGLE_ABUSE_EXEMPTION=ID=52cecb7a44e552cc:TM=1442301156:C=c:IP=88.51.233.126-:S=APGng0tXDRxFvrRNJHu-uk3IRqKVpJAIIQ"); //This is the cookie of the request of Firefox
```

Google sends the translated sentence `"जीवन महान है और इस पर और पर और पर चला जाता है जब एक खराब है"`

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12711/Google-Translator) is a project that seems to work, it basically add different parameters in the url.

> GoogleTranslator works by directly invoking Google's translation API
>   called by its online translation form and parsing the results.

Comment: It seems my question should be, how to skip captcha?. Fantastic Edit ... lemme see what can we do

Comment: @MohitShrivastava I edited the answer with a link to a Google Translate API invoker

Comment: Lemme have a look on it. If it works I'll mark this as answer

Comment: That is not working as expected. But I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to use the Google TTS as well, but it doesn't work anymore. The Google Translate v2 doesn't support TTS anymore [(see here)](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest)

Since you are using C# you could better use the speechsynthesis with System.Speech.Synthesis

```
 public static void TextToSpeech (string utterance)
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer speaker = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        speaker.Speak(utterance);
        return;
    }
```

Hope this answers a bit of your question. There are no workarounds for the captcha as of yet.