# google Translation API throwing 503 error

Tags: google-translation-api

We are getting the error in google Translation. API throwing 503 Server unavailable loading error.

We have licenses API_KEY.
Error from the Raw HTTP action. Error during GET request. 500 Internal Server Error loading from https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=API_KEY&source=fr&target=en&q=Cin%C3%A9maEau%20de%20Parfum

Error from the Click action. The action failed after 3 attempts. Error loading resource: http://www.nocibe.fr/preparateur-solaire/visage/C-62816, Error return code 404, info: Not Found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-language Google Translate API is returing (503) Server Unavailable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579641/multi-language-google-translate-api-is-returing-503-server-unavailable)

Answer (score 3):

About HTTP error code 503, I have got this error when I have send more than 5000 characters per request.

About other HTTP errors you can read at [API FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq)